# Update function based on categorical values python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

```
    MatchId ExpectedGoals_Team1 ExpectedGoals_Team2 Timestamp         Stages        Home              Away
0   698085  0.8585339288573895  1.4819072820614578  2016-08-13 11:30:00  0        [92, 112]            [94]
1   698086  1.097064295289673   1.0923520385902274  2016-09-12 14:00:00  0        []                   [164]
2   698087  1.2752442136224664  0.8687263006179976  2016-11-25 14:00:00  1        [90]                 [147]
3   698088  1.0571269856980154  1.4323522262211752  2016-02-16 14:00:00  2        [10, 66, 101]        [50, 118]
4   698089  1.2680212913301165  0.918961072480616   2016-05-10 14:00:00  2        [21]                 [134, 167]
```

Here is the function that needs to be updating the outcomes based on the categorized column **'Stages'**.

```
x1 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
x2 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
x3 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
total_timeslot = 196
m=1

def squared_diff(row):
    ssd = []
    Home = row.Home
    Away = row.Away
    y = np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m])
for k in range(total_timeslot):          
    if k in Home:
        ssd.append(sum((x2 - y) ** 2))
    elif k in Away:
        ssd.append(sum((x3 - y) ** 2))
    else:
        ssd.append(sum((x1 - y) ** 2))
return sum(ssd)

sum(df.apply(squared_diff, axis=1)) 
For m=1, Out[400]: 7636.305551658377
```

By assigning an arbitrary value of `m` for each category in `Stages` I want to test a cost function. `Let m1 = 2, m2 = 3.`

Here is how I attempted.

```
def stages(row):
    Stages = row.Stages
    if Stages == 0:
        return np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m])
    elif Stages == 1:
        return np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m1 + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m1), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m1, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m1])
    else:
        return np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m2 + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m2), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m2, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m2])

df.apply(squared_diff, Stages, axis=1)
```

> TypeError: apply() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is ````Stages_So````, and how are stages and squared_diff related...? Are you using the output of one in the other? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, Stage_So was a typo. It should be 'Stages'. 'squared_diff' is the cost func. 'Stages' is a category col. I want to apply squared_diff to df while assigning different values of m to different categories in 'Stages'. I hope this made it clearer.

Comment: I think you can assign the results of stages() to a column (say 'stage_cat') ````df['stage_cat'] = df.apply(stages,axis = 1)````, and pass that in squared_diff(), but I don't see how squared_diff() makes use of stages either.

Comment: All squared_diff() takes are Home, Away, .ExpectedGoals_Team1, and ExpectedGoals_Team2. Where exactly do you want stages to appear? You need to modify your function.

Comment: I want Stages to update the constant m in y for each cat. which subsequently used in squred_diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.apply(squared_diff, Stages, axis=1)` got error because the second parameter is for `axis` so it thought `axis=Stages`, but then the third parameter is again `axis=1`.

To address the problem, you can first store desired `m` into a separate column

```
df['m'] = df.Stages.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else 2 if x == 1 else 3)
```

Then replace this line in your squared_diff function

```
y = np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*m, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*m])
```

with

```
y = np.array([1 - (row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*row.m + row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*row.m), row.ExpectedGoals_Team1*row.m, row.ExpectedGoals_Team2*row.m])
```

Comment: But to work out the cost function I need to use the function squared_diff.

Comment: Updated to use squared_diff